# Throwing ResponseStatusException in controller returns no body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

When I throw a `ResponseStatusException`, I get a completely empty body. Just `{}`. I'm still getting the correct error code. I'm not using any `ControllerAdvice` annotiations anywhere and I added `server.error.include-message=always` to the `application.properties` file. I notice that other people have an issue where they have an empty message such as with:

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-1-26T12:34:26.416+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/hello"
}
```

but I don't even get a body. This is what the method in my controller looks like. I have other methods in the same controller that will return responses to the client with the correct body, just not when exceptions are thrown. Currently using Spring Boot 2.3.7

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public String testError() {
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Invalid");
}
```

Comment: You're masking the error controller. Use a different path.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks!